# Concerns with ActiveSupport::Concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am in need of adding set of generic methods to an existing model. I've found this tutorial:

http://chris-schmitz.com/extending-activemodel-via-activesupportconcern/

which in my opinion is what I am aiming at (I want to have a module which will be added to the model to add some methods to it - a sort of mixin).

Now even if I do plain copy paste from the tutorial I am struck at the following error (with no further explanation):

```
undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass
```

Here is what my model looks like:

```
class Folder < ActiveRecord::Base  
  attr_accessible :name, :parent_id  

  has_default

  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

The moment I remove **has_default** everything goes back to normal

Comment: Where's your module which includes ActiveSupport::Concern?

Comment: The one that is extending ActiveSupport::Concern is based inside /lib library of my project.

Answer (score 5):

Check agains your code...

The modules structure may look like this (taken from one of my projects that definitely works):

```
# lib/taggable.rb

require 'active_support/concern'

module Taggable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def taggable
      include TaggableMethods # includes the instance methods specified in the TaggableMethods module
      # class methods, validations and other class stuff...
    end
  end

  module TaggableMethods
    # instance methods...
  end
end
```

What is missing is that you should  tell Rails to load the module from the `lib` directory:

```
# config/application.rb

module AppName
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)

    # rest ommited...
```

Now the modules should be included.

```
# model.rb

class Model
  taggable

end
```

This is how basic plugins works. The author of the tutorial mentioned in your question writes a plugin specific only for models that inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base` for he is using its specific methods (e.g. `update_column`).

If your modules does no rely on ActiveRecord methods, it is not necessary to extend it (the module may also be used by Mongoid models). But this is definitely **NOT** the right way:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  include HasDefault
end
```

If you really need to extend ActiveRecord, do it this way:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.extend ModuleName
```

Of course there are lots of other ways to write plugins depending on your needs, take various rails `gems` as a good inspiration.

Comment: Same thing; just copy pasted code from your answer and I am getting the same error - undefined method `key?' for nil:NilClass

I was developing from windows, so right now I am installing rails on my Macbook Air - lets see if problem is there.

Comment: Well absolutely the same error both on newest MacOs and ubuntu 12.10

Comment: Can you please extend your question with more lines from the exception backtrace including line numbers? I am sure it must be something really trivial. Thanks.

Comment: The thing is that there is nothing more - entire backtrace is empty except for that error. Thats the only non empty line in there is the error I provided.